# Straight GDI Programming in C on Windows

Tags: winapi, c99

I have taken a recent interest in programming as efficiently as possible for Windows in straight C. I still want a GUI for some things, is the Windows API/GDI still the respectable way to go about this? I don't believe you can make regular calls for WPF, since it is largely a managed affair. Is GDI really un-accelerated under Vista/Win7? If so, is there another alternative to get hardware accelerated GUIs from straight C? (Other than perhaps the roll-yer-own approach with OpenGL)

Also, Petzold used to be the gold standard for picking up Windows API programming with C, is there a newer edition of his materials, or has someone else taken up the mantle? The last edition I saw is from 1999...

Comment: You mentioned "hardware accelerated". Is performance an issue for your application? Are you just doing buttons and windows, or are you doing 3d graphics?

Comment: No 3D graphics at this stage, but possibly some spectrum-analyzer type displays, so a little performance would be good. Basically my concept is a kind-of "soft synthesizer" with a reasonably nice UI. Mostly will be buttons-and-slider type stuff, but some graphs/envelopes etc.

Comment: AFIK, wpf uses directx. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/greg_schechter/archive/2006/05/02/588934.aspx

Comment: I would love a link to some site that states that Windows 6 did/does not have hardware accelerated GDI.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Microsoft has a page comparing [GDI vs Direct2D](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff729480%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) hardware acceleration.

GDI always has been an accelerated API: of course, it was always left up to the actual GDI driver implementation to decide which bits of the GDI DDI to actually accelerate so its usually been the bitblt / stretch blit operations that have been accelerated, and all the line drawing and other effects are done by CPU.

some people take this as a sign that GDI is no longer "good enough" compared to newer APIs but frankly *all* graphics really revolves down to moving rects around.

GdiPlus is implemented in software, and so, as a result, is the system.graphics CLR implementation.

Comment: Accepted on the basis that this response is the closest to a direct answer of my questions. Bonus points for linking to an appropriate MSDN page.

Answer (score 0):

DirectX is in general much faster than GDI, due to the fact that it has full acceleration on most video cards. GDI may have some acceleration (on Windows 7 and XP, but not Vista), but DirectX is still the way to go.

Book wise, Petzold is all about WPF these days: [Programming Windows Three Dimensional Presentation Foundation](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735623945)